# How do you set initial size in iOS UIMapkit

Tags: ios, core-location

I want my mapView to display at the initial size (zoom level I determine) with phone location being centred in the map. Once this is done I want the user to be able to change zoom levels and pan to their hearts content. Next time they come into the app I want to reinitialise the map the same as the previous time.

Problem is when I come in it seems to set the map size before it has got a valid location fix.

Can anyone point me at an example that does best practice initialisation?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in next way. I think code is self-explained

```
      - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!_userLocated && 
        userLocation.coordinate.latitude != 0.0 && 
        userLocation.coordinate.longitude != 0.0)
    {
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
        mapRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04);
        [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        _userLocated = YES;
    }
}
```

And dont forget to set `UIMapView` delegate and `Shows user location`.